# php stream_socket_client unable to connect tcp://localhost

Tags: php, yii

I am getting following error when **stream_socket_client()** is called

> unable to connect to tcp://localhost:24224 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. )

Comment: Is the port 24224 open on your target machine?

Comment: yes it is open, I've opened it using following guide  http://www.wikihow.com/Open-Ports

Comment: It's kind of hard to say what's going wrong without more information. What are you trying to connect to on the other end?